# how to assign variable value in an anonymous class java

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-room

I want to assign a result value to my list variable,but a variable in lambda must be final and if it is final,it can't receive a value.

```
public List<PersonalInfo> getAllPatient() {

    List<PersonalInfo> mPersonalInfoList;
    AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(mContext);
    db.patientDao().getAll()
            .flatMapIterable(patientlist -> {
                    List<PersonalInfo> personalInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (PersonalInfo p: patientlist) {
                        p.setColor(getRandomMaterialColor("400"));
                        personalInfoList.add(p);
                    }
                    return  personalInfoList;
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result ->
               // error
                mPersonalInfoList =result
             );
    return mPersonalInfoList;
}
```

Comment: This requires blocking the thread that calls `getAllPatient`. Why do you want this? Can't you just return the `Single<List<PersonalInfo>>` and have the code handling the list in `subscribe(list -> ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue there is that your method returns before the value is assigned to your variable. You can solve this issue with a lock.

Try this:

```
public List<PersonalInfo> getAllPatient() {
    final List<PersonalInfo> mPersonalInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(mContext);
    db.patientDao().getAll()
            .flatMapIterable(patientlist -> {
                    List<PersonalInfo> personalInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (PersonalInfo p : patientlist) {
                        p.setColor(getRandomMaterialColor("400"));
                        personalInfoList.add(p);
                    }
                    return  personalInfoList;
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> {
                synchronized (mPersonalInfoList) {
                    mPersonalInfoList.addAll(result);
                    mPersonalInfoList.notifyAll();
                }
              }
            );

    synchronized (mPersonalInfoList) {
            try {
                mPersonalInfoList.wait();
            } catch (InterrupedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    return mPersonalInfoList;
}
```

Comment: this is making the app UI freeze

Comment: That's probably because the lambda expression passed to `subscribe` is never called.

Answer (score -1):

You may convert your local variable to a class member, it should fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in your case you can initialize mPersonalInfoList and instead of assigning your result, add it to mPersonalInfoList.

So:

```
final List<PersonalInfo> mPersonalInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

...

.subscribe(result ->
    mPersonalInfoList.addAll(result);
);
```

Comment: This would return an empty list.

Comment: the List is ruturning a null value out of the inner class